# Point Cloud Unity example only renders points for the upper half of display

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

We are trying to get the Point Cloud Unity example to work.
We tried both the example from the git: 
https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/tree/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Examples/PointCloud

As well as the Depth Perception Tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-prefab-depth

But we only get points rendered on the upper half of the screen for some reason. 
When we quickly tilt our device up we can see more points but as soon as the renderer catches up they disappear again.

We are pretty sure it worked with older versions but we might be mistaking. 
We use Unity 5.3.3 and the Unity SDK is Gemma (Version 1.31, February 2016).

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Well done on getting a kit

Comment: Is the point cloud rendered using Unity's particle system? I used it to render sunk then scanned in 3D ships and whenever the particle system's origin got out of frustrum, the entire particles system was no longer rendered even if some particles did were in frustrum. The solution I had back then was to subdivide the particles system into N others and to recenter each system on its centroid. The problem remained but was minimized as N grew.

Comment: Hi Timothy, this is because the device extrinsics not being applied to the deltaPoseController in the scene. The depth camera has ~13 degree rotation pointing a little bit up. However, the device pose is being reported with out that 13 degree rotation. I think this should be fixed. But do you mind let me know what's your use case? I can probably help you solve the problem directly rather than help you fix delta pose controller.

Answer (score 0):

the TangoDeltaPoseController and TangoPoseController in Unity all assume Unity Camera Frame was aligned with the Device （Default） Frame， so the matrix dTuc was
a constant matrix

```
m_dTuc = new Matrix4x4();
m_dTuc.SetColumn(0, new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
m_dTuc.SetColumn(1, new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
m_dTuc.SetColumn(2, new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
m_dTuc.SetColumn(3, new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

but for AR or point cloud like apps, the overlay image or the point cloud was
captured by the color/depth camera, the m_dTuc need an extra transformation instead of using the default constant matrix

in the TangoARPoseController it was

```
// Get the transformation of device frame with respect to IMU frame.
        pair.baseFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU;
        pair.targetFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;
        PoseProvider.GetPoseAtTime(poseData, timestamp, pair);
        Matrix4x4 imuTd = poseData.ToMatrix4x4();

        // Get the transformation of IMU frame with respect to color camera frame.
        pair.baseFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU;
        pair.targetFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR;
        PoseProvider.GetPoseAtTime(poseData, timestamp, pair);
        Matrix4x4 imuTc = poseData.ToMatrix4x4();

        // Get the transform of the Unity Camera frame with respect to the Color Camera frame.
        Matrix4x4 cTuc = new Matrix4x4();
        cTuc.SetColumn(0, new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        cTuc.SetColumn(1, new Vector4(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        cTuc.SetColumn(2, new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        cTuc.SetColumn(3, new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

        m_dTuc = Matrix4x4.Inverse(imuTd) * imuTc * cTuc;
```

I hope this would help you.