# Google Tango - Getting pose data with IMU as base frame

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I am working with Google Project Tango and I tried a basic example with getting pose data:

```
TangoCoordinateFramePair pair;
pair.base = TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE;
pair.target = TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR;
base = TANGO_SUPPORT_ENGINE_OPENGL;
target = TANGO_SUPPORT_ENGINE_OPENGL;
error = TangoSupport_getPoseAtTime(poseTimestamp, pair.base, pair.target, base, target, ROTATION_0, &pose);
```

This gives TANGO_SUCCESS.

However, if I only change base to this

`pair.base = TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU;`

...I keep getting TANGO_INVALID.

I tried using C API and Unity SDK, and both have a same invalid result.
Why is that? Why can't I use TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU?

I am trying to fix Camera offset as mentioned here:
[Camera-Offset | Project Tango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476910/camera-offset-project-tango)
but without any success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TangoSupport_getPoseAtTime`](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/support/reference/group/transformation-support#group___transformation_support_1ga7d758b5573ec084cce0aa2313d17cf5d) only works for getting a pose between a fixed coordinate frame and a moving coordinate frame.  The `TANGO_INVALID` error results from the fact that `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR` and  `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU` are both moving coordinate frames.

In order to find the offset between `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU` and `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR` (or between any pair of moving coordinate frames), you need to use [`TangoService_getPoseAtTime`](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/reference/group/pose#group___pose_1ga5b28d1d9a6b8c7703edd7c45e289177b) instead.

This code snippet should give you the transform you're looking for:

```
TangoCoordinateFramePair pair;
pair.base = TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU;
pair.target = TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR;
TangoPoseData pose;
TangoErrorType result = TangoService_getPoseAtTime(0.0, pair, &pose);
```

Note also that since both of these coordinate frames are moving (i.e. in a fixed position with respect to the device, and each other) the pose resulting from this call will not change as the device moves.